# New hardware (Intel i3-8300, old = N3150) with same OS (LTS 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, hardware

I just bought new hardware (Intel i3-8300 + Asus ROG STRIX H370-I GAMING) which I want to replace and Intel N3150 + Asrock N3150DC-ITX. Both systems have 16G RAM. Would this work by just moving the old HDD containing the OS (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) to the new hardware? or the OS will just fail to boot or to allow login?

**UPDATE**

- using onboard video for both systems
- I have no WIFI but only ethernet (2x)
- I'm afraiding about network interfaces issues, e.g.:

  - the new interfaces have other names & settings and they should somehow come into /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ at least
  - the new interfaces have overlapping names but other settings

Comment: It is possible that the system works in both of these computers. There may be problems if you have a proprietary graphics driver, that does not work in the other computer. In that case you need to remove the proprietary driver and **maybe** replace it with another one. -- The same applies for the wifi, if you use wifi. It is also possible that you need the newest possible version of Ubuntu for the new hardware. [This link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865) may help.

Comment: Ethernet is very standardized, and most hardware works with the built-in linux drivers. - If you installed from an Ubuntu Desktop iso file, the network system is portable. It is different  if you installed from a `mini.iso` or Ubuntu Server iso file.

Comment: If you have the same kind of interface, for example SATA, you can easily move the drive with Ubuntu to the new computer and try. If you want to play safe, you can clone it with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org) to a new drive, or make a good backup before you try. (I have ported systems between computers many times without any damage, even when it did not boot correctly in the new computer, but you can never be sure).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of hardware, you'll be fine.  Linux detects all hardware on every startup, so as long as you have a standard Ubuntu generic kernel and hardware it supports, hardware changes won't be an issue.

However, as you note, different network hardware may be assigned different device names in Ubuntu 16.x or later, which may require you to know how to detect the network device names to do certain things.  It's very likely that Ubuntu will just start up and work, but if (for instance) you have a Conky that tracks network connectivity or performance, its config will need to be edited to reflect the new network device names.

As noted in comments, if you have or need proprietary graphics drivers, Ubuntu may start up with free/open drivers for the new machine's graphics hardware, or with a fallback video driver -- generally, except for specific issues, you'll likely still have a GUI if you had one before the rebuild, but it may be low resolution and slow until you install or select the correct compatible driver.